# Using already created functions inside a new Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I'm beginner, so this question might be silly.
I had to do 4 Javascript Function, I will put them below

```
    function Square(a) {
        b=a*a;
        return b;
     }

    //2.Functia Half//
    function Half(a) {
        b=a/2;
        return b;

    }

    //3.Functia Percent//
    function Percent(a,b) {
        procent=a/b*100;
        return procent + "%";

    }

    //4.Functia Area//
    function Area(a) {
        pi=3.14;
        circlearea=a*a*pi;
        final=circlearea.toFixed(0);
        return final;
    }
```

Now i have to create the last function, which does:

Applies Half function on the parameter I've given to the new function(a), stores is in a new variable(result), result becomes parameter for the function square, the result will be stored again in a new variable(resultSquare), resultSquare will be used in Area function and stored in a new variable(resultArea). In the end, I need percent function, to find out the percent of resultArea from resultSquare. I tried like this, but no luck:

```
        function new function{
        result=Half(a);
        return result;
        resultSquare=Square(result);
        return resultSquare;
      }
```

It just returns result variable and does nothing else. Can you help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You only want one `result` per execution path in an function, as the return exits the function, so your first `return` shouldn't be there.  And `function new function{` is not valid syntax.  Function declarations need to look just like you have done prior.

Comment: You should really get used to **declaring** variables in your functions with `var` or `let`. As it is most of your variables are *global*.

Comment: Also use `Math.PI` instead of declaring your own constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `result` exits the function - so anything after a `return` statement will not be run. You need to return the last item:

```
function newFunction(a) {
    var result = Half(a);
    var resultSquare = Square(a);
    var resultArea = Area(a);
    return Percent(resultSquare, resultArea);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! How can the Percent function return only 2 digits after ,? Like xx.yy%

Comment: No problem whatsoever @AlexandruSalitrarovici, if my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with what Percent returns please? I know about ".toFixed(2);", but I don't know how to use it when I return in this case.

Comment: Just do `return Percent(resultSquare, resultArea).split("").pop().join("").toFixed(2).split("").push("%").join("")`

Answer (score 1):

You can't `return` something twice. Once  you return something, it breaks out of the function. Remove the first `return result;` statement and it should work.

Also why are you doing

```
function new function { }
```

The proper syntax is

```
function [Function Name](parameters) { }
```

Comment: Do you mean when I'm creating new functions or when I'm calling them? Because I've never called one yet and for creating them since like it works with that syntax.

Comment: @AlexandruSalitrarovici creating. If it works for you, you can keep doing it. I just didn't think it would work